# Flutter Menu and Navigation

Tags: dart, navigation, flutter

I'm quite new with Flutter and I'm coming from using the Angular framework. Currently, I'm experimenting with flutter to make a desktop application using the following flutter embedding project: https://github.com/Drakirus/go-flutter-desktop-embedder.

I was wondering if someone could explain to me the best way to implement the following:

The black box represents the application as a whole.

The red box represents the custom menu.

The green box represents the content of the page.

How would I go about routing between "widgets" inside of the green area without changing the widget holding the application?

I'd love some direction please.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm a noob so please take anything I say with a grain of salt.
I know 2 ways to navigate through widgets and you can find them both here
https://flutter.io/docs/development/ui/navigation
I believe the main difference I can perceive is if you want to
send data to the new 'route' or not (the named route way cannot, at least that I'm aware of);

said so you can keep your main 'screen' and change the red and green widget
using the state of the widget where they are contained

example

```
class BlackWidget extends StatefulWidget 
bla bla bla => BlackWidgetState();

class BlackWidget extend State<BlackWidget>

Widget tallWidget = GreenWidget();
Widget bigWidget = RedWidget();
return
container, column.. etc
Row(
children:[tallWidget,bigWidget
])
button onTap => tallWidget = YellowWidget();
}

GreenWidget... bla bla bla...
onPressed: () {
  Navigator.push(
    context,
    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => RedWidget()),
  );
}
```

sorry for the 'bla bla', the part you need is at the bottom,
just added the 'yellow' widget to underline that you can
actually swap the 'green widget' with anything you want

Answer (score 0):

I am contributing Drakirus 's go-flutter plugin. 
This projecd had moved to https://github.com/go-flutter-desktop

The question you ask can use package responsive_scaffold 
https://pub.dev/packages/responsive_scaffold 
or 
you can reference this doc https://iirokrankka.com/2018/01/28/implementing-adaptive-master-detail-layouts/ 
Basically, there two are different layouts, see comments for detail

```
class _MasterDetailContainerState extends State<MasterDetailContainer> {
  // Track the currently selected item here. Only used for
  // tablet layouts.
  Item _selectedItem;

  Widget _buildMobileLayout() {
    return ItemListing(
      // Since we're on mobile, just push a new route for the
      // item details.
      itemSelectedCallback: (item) {
        Navigator.push(...);
      },
    );
  }

  Widget _buildTabletLayout() {
    // For tablets, return a layout that has item listing on the left
    // and item details on the right.
    return Row(
      children: <Widget>[
        Flexible(
          flex: 1, 
          child: ItemListing(
            // Instead of pushing a new route here, we update
            // the currently selected item, which is a part of
            // our state now.
            itemSelectedCallback: (item) {
              setState(() {
                _selectedItem = item;
              });
            },
          ),
        ),
        Flexible(
          flex: 3,
          child: ItemDetails(
            // The item details just blindly accepts whichever
            // item we throw in its way, just like before.
            item: _selectedItem,
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
```

For package responsive_scaffold 
on-line demo https://fluttercommunity.github.io/responsive_scaffold/#/ 
github https://github.com/fluttercommunity/responsive_scaffold/

[image]

more template code snippets for layout 
https://github.com/fluttercommunity/responsive_scaffold/tree/dev

more pictures and demo can found here https://github.com/fluttercommunity/responsive_scaffold/tree/dev/lib/templates/3-column 
code snippet 1

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'package:responsive_scaffold/responsive_scaffold.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  var _scaffoldKey = new GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: ResponsiveListScaffold.builder(
        scaffoldKey: _scaffoldKey,
        detailBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index, bool tablet) {
          return DetailsScreen(
            // appBar: AppBar(
            //   elevation: 0.0,
            //   title: Text("Details"),
            //   actions: [
            //     IconButton(
            //       icon: Icon(Icons.share),
            //       onPressed: () {},
            //     ),
            //     IconButton(
            //       icon: Icon(Icons.delete),
            //       onPressed: () {
            //         if (!tablet) Navigator.of(context).pop();
            //       },
            //     ),
            //   ],
            // ),
            body: Scaffold(
              appBar: AppBar(
                elevation: 0.0,
                title: Text("Details"),
                automaticallyImplyLeading: !tablet,
                actions: [
                  IconButton(
                    icon: Icon(Icons.share),
                    onPressed: () {},
                  ),
                  IconButton(
                    icon: Icon(Icons.delete),
                    onPressed: () {
                      if (!tablet) Navigator.of(context).pop();
                    },
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              bottomNavigationBar: BottomAppBar(
                elevation: 0.0,
                child: Container(
                  child: IconButton(
                    icon: Icon(Icons.share),
                    onPressed: () {},
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              body: Container(
                child: Center(
                  child: Text("Item: $index"),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          );
        },
        nullItems: Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()),
        emptyItems: Center(child: Text("No Items Found")),
        slivers: <Widget>[
          SliverAppBar(
            title: Text("App Bar"),
          ),
        ],
        itemCount: 100,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          return ListTile(
            leading: Text(index.toString()),
          );
        },
        bottomNavigationBar: BottomAppBar(
          elevation: 0.0,
          child: Container(
            child: IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.share),
              onPressed: () {},
            ),
          ),
        ),
        floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
          child: Icon(Icons.add),
          onPressed: () {
            _scaffoldKey.currentState.showSnackBar(SnackBar(
              content: Text("Snackbar!"),
            ));
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

code snippet 2

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:responsive_scaffold/responsive_scaffold.dart';

class MultiColumnNavigationExample extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ThreeColumnNavigation(
      title: Text('Mailboxes'),
      showDetailsArrows: true,
      backgroundColor: Colors.grey[100],
      bottomAppBar: BottomAppBar(
        elevation: 1,
        child: Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            IconButton(
              icon: Icon(
                Icons.filter_list,
                color: Colors.transparent,
              ),
              onPressed: () {},
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      sections: [
        MainSection(
          label: Text('All Inboxes'),
          icon: Icon(Icons.mail),
          itemCount: 100,
          itemBuilder: (context, index, selected) {
            return ListTile(
              leading: CircleAvatar(
                child: Text(index.toString()),
              ),
              selected: selected,
              title: Text('Primary Information'),
              subtitle: Text('Here are some details about the item'),
            );
          },
          bottomAppBar: BottomAppBar(
            elevation: 1,
            child: Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                IconButton(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.filter_list),
                  onPressed: () {},
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          getDetails: (context, index) {
            return DetailsWidget(
              title: Text('Details'),
              child: Center(
                child: Text(
                  index.toString(),
                ),
              ),
            );
          },
        ),
        MainSection(
          label: Text('Sent Mail'),
          icon: Icon(Icons.send),
          itemCount: 100,
          itemBuilder: (context, index, selected) {
            return ListTile(
              leading: CircleAvatar(
                child: Text(index.toString()),
              ),
              selected: selected,
              title: Text('Secondary Information'),
              subtitle: Text('Here are some details about the item'),
            );
          },
          getDetails: (context, index) {
            return DetailsWidget(
              title: Text('Details'),
              actions: [
                IconButton(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.share),
                  onPressed: () {},
                ),
              ],
              child: Center(
                child: Text(
                  index.toString(),
                ),
              ),
            );
          },
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```